# How to remove or replace a multiline text between two patterns

Tags: python, shell, awk, sed, substitution

I would like to add some customer flags in some of my scripts for it to be parsed before packaging by a shell script.

Let's say, removing all multiline text between

`^([#]|[//]){0,1}[_]+NOT_FOR_CUSTOMER_BEGIN[_]+\n`

and between

`^([#]|[//]){0,1}[_]+NOT_FOR_CUSTOMER_END[_]+\n`

I want it to be error tolerant (about the number of '_') that is why i'm using regexes.

For instance:

#### before.foo

```
i want this
#____NOT_FOR_CUSTOMER_BEGIN________
not this
nor this
#________NOT_FOR_CUSTOMER_END____
and this
//____NOT_FOR_CUSTOMER_BEGIN__
not this again
nor this again
//__________NOT_FOR_CUSTOMER_END____
and this again
```

will become:

#### after.foo

```
i want this
and this
and this again
```

I'd rather use sed but any clever solution will be welcomed :)

Something like this:

```
cat before.foo |  tr '\n' '\a' | sed -r 's/([#]|[//]){0,1}[_]+NOT_FOR_CUSTOMER_BEGIN[_]+\a.*\a([#]|[//]){0,1}[_]+NOT_FOR_CUSTOMER_END[_]+\a/\a/g' | tr '\a' '\n' > after.foo
```

Comment: Which tool/programming language?

Comment: shell script, thank you

Comment: It is not shell but `^(?:#|//)_+NOT_FOR_CUSTOMER_BEGIN_+(?:\s.+)*?\R(?:#|//)_+NOT_FOR_CUSTOMER_END_+\s*` https://regex101.com/r/Qj2T59/1

Comment: it is working indeed but how can i call it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`sed` is easiest tool to handle this as it can delete lines from a start pattern to end patter:

```sh
sed -E '/_+NOT_FOR_CUSTOMER_BEGIN_+/,/_+NOT_FOR_CUSTOMER_END_+/d' file

i want this
and this
and this again
```

If you are looking for `awk` solution then here is a simpler `awk`:

```sh
awk '/_+NOT_FOR_CUSTOMER_BEGIN_+/,/_+NOT_FOR_CUSTOMER_END_+/{next} 1' file
```

Comment: prettiest solution. I knew that sed could do the job :)

Answer (score 4):

Have `awk` solution in this way, written and tested with your shown samples.

```
awk '
/^([#]|[/][/])__+NOT_FOR_CUSTOMER_BEGIN/{ found=1       }
/^([#]|[/][/])__+NOT_FOR_CUSTOMER_END/  { found=""; next}
!found
'  Input_file
```

With your shown samples, output will be as follows.

```
i want this
and this
and this again
```

***Explanation:*** Simple explanation is: whenever start string(with regex) is found make a flag to TRUE(for non printing) and whenever end string(with regex check) comes Nullify the flag to start printing(depending upon the lines) next line onwards.

Answer (score 3):

You could use a `Python` script:

```
import re

data = """
i want this
#____NOT_FOR_CUSTOMER_BEGIN________
not this
nor this
#________NOT_FOR_CUSTOMER_END____
and this
//____NOT_FOR_CUSTOMER_BEGIN__
not this again
nor this again
//__________NOT_FOR_CUSTOMER_END____
and this again
"""

rx = re.compile(r'^(#|//)(?:.+\n)+^\1.+\n?', re.MULTILINE)
data = rx.sub('', data)
print(data)
```

Which would yield

```
i want this
and this
and this again
```

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/zS8LaS/1).

Answer (score 3):

You could match as least as possible lines from `NOT_FOR_CUSTOMER_BEGIN_` till `NOT_FOR_CUSTOMER_END_`

Note that `[//]` matches a single `/` instead of `//`

```
^(?:#|//)_+NOT_FOR_CUSTOMER_BEGIN_+(?:\n.*)*?\n(?:#|//)_+NOT_FOR_CUSTOMER_END_+\n*
```

- `^` Start of string
- `(?:#|//)` Match either `#` or `//`
- `_+NOT_FOR_CUSTOMER_BEGIN_+` Match `NOT_FOR_CUSTOMER_BEGIN` between 1 or more underscores
- `(?:\n.*)*?` Repeat as least as possible lines
- `\n(?:#|//)_+NOT_FOR_CUSTOMER_END_+` Match a newline, then either `#` or `//` and  `NOT_FOR_CUSTOMER_END_` between one or more underscores
- `\n*` Remove optional trailing newlines

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Qq65H3/1)

Another way to use it with Python:

```
import re

regex = r"^(?:#|//)_+NOT_FOR_CUSTOMER_BEGIN_+(?:\n.+)*?\n(?:#|//)_+NOT_FOR_CUSTOMER_END_+\n*"

s = ("i want this\n"
            "#____NOT_FOR_CUSTOMER_BEGIN________\n"
            "not this\n"
            "nor this\n"
            "#________NOT_FOR_CUSTOMER_END____\n"
            "and this\n"
            "//____NOT_FOR_CUSTOMER_BEGIN__\n"
            "not this again\n"
            "nor this again\n"
            "//__________NOT_FOR_CUSTOMER_END____\n"
            "and this again")

subst = ""
result = re.sub(regex, "", s, 0, re.MULTILINE)

if result:
    print (result)
```

Output

```
i want this
and this
and this again
```